# Mac and Excel Pivots not happy... repair errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, pivot-table

[image]

I have Microsoft Office for Mac on my iMAC computer running OS X Yosemite 8GB memory. I have an EXCEL file with 6000 rows & building pivots, VLOOKUPs etc. Excel running V15.28

My questions, is it normal for MS EXCEL (V15.28) working in Mac to 'lose' data and show errors relating to 'Repairing'?

Every time I open the file it comes up with an error. The file has 'repaired' in the file name now AND I really think it is missing amendments that I have done to the data from one day to the next...

Comment: "sorry for all the background" - don't say that,  just remove it, currently 80+% of your text is irrelevant.  And please add more useful details: which are the exact version you use to open the file? Have you tried to edit your file in Excel online?

Comment: I have edited my questions.. do you have any answers, suggestions Mate Juhasz? Thank you

Comment: do you have issue with that file only? Does it work on other computers / online ?....

Comment: it brings up the same error when I posted the file in OneDrive. Its the only file I have that big with pivots. Should I try a file I created on a PC base Excel and work on it via my Mac?